# #VALUE error in Column G when Column C cells are blank

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have the following formula which manipulates the string in Column C and returns that value in Column G:

```
Range("G1").Select
Range("G:G").Value = "=MID(C1,18,LEN(C1)-22)"
```

But now I have an issue. The above formula fills up the cells in Column G infinitely, returning `#VALUE` error when cells in Column C are blank.

Is there a way to restrict the `Range("G:G").Value` in the formula to fill up Column G only if cells in Column C have a value?

Thanks!

Comment: Rather why can't you handle error in the formula itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this which is the [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) equivalent of

- identifying the used portion of column `C`
- putting a formula in the corresponding `G` column of `=IF(LEN(C1)>22,MID(C1,18,LEN(C1)-22),"")`
- removing the formula (and any `""`) with the `.Value`

**code**

```
   Sub G_Spot()
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Set rng1 = Range([c1], Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
    With rng1.Offset(0, 4)
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(LEN(RC[-4])>22,MID(RC[-4],18,LEN(RC[-4])-22),"""")"
            .Value = .Value
    End With
    End Sub
```